# How to update order total, subtotal and discount in WooCommerce checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to Update order total, subtotal and discount in checkout page pragmatically but not happening that. Please help

I have tried by default WooCommerce hooks but didn't not get proper solution. Thank you

Comment: On which action, and why do you need to update it programmatically you said you tried but didn't tell me what and how did you try? Please share enough information to understand your expectation and what kind of errors you're getting with your code.

Comment: @VijayHardaha thank you so much for your kind response. I am recalculating discount cart page total, subtotal by below custom form, but when I click for Proceed to check out there recalculate value does not appear in checkout page

Comment: function add_content(){  
    ?> 
    <form method="post"> 
        <input type="submit" name="takeway" value="Takeway"/> 
    </form>

<?php

}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'add_content');


add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'elex_discount_price' ); 

function elex_discount_price($cart) 
{ 
global $woocommerce; //Set the price for user role. 

if(isset($_POST['takeway'])) {
$discount_price = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal * 40 / 100;  

$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Discounted Price', -$discount_price, true, 'standard' ); 
}
}

Comment: I think I have already commented on your other question about this problem.